# i keep getting the same error when i try to import an image wheter its png,jpg or svg. module not found: cant resolve?

Tags: reactjs, image, svg, import, jpeg

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg"

function NavBar() {
    return (
        <div className="navBar">
        <button>Manual</button>
        <button>Scenarios</button>
        <button><img src={logo}/></button>
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
        </div>
    );
}
export default NavBar;
```

I am getting this:
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/components/NavBar.jsx 5:0-30

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './logo.svg' in 'C:\Users\andri\Documents\myReact\rushing-ranges\src\components'
```

I have tried importing from folder images and also from root of src directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use require keyword when giving path

```
 <img src={require('./logo.svg')}/>
```

Comment: tried that, same error still.
it says:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './logo.svg' in 'C:\Users\andri\Documents\myReact\rushing-ranges\src\components'
but "components" is a subfolder of src it should not be looking there should be in src?

Comment: make sure path is right